# Optimize SQL by SUBSTRING or chunk column

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

What is the best way in optimizing this certain query?

For example I have 10 digit phone number and I wanted to query either of these two.

1. WHERE columnName start from 123456
2. WHERE columnName1 = 123 OR columnName2 = 456

.

**First: Using SUBSTRING**

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE SUBSTRING(telephone, 1,6)
```

Data:

```
  id  |  telephone
   1  |  1234560001 
   2  |  1234560002
```

**Second: By chunking column into pieces**

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE pt1 = 123 AND pt2 = 456

SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE pt1 = 123 OR pt2 = 456
```

Data:

```
  id  |   pt1 | pt2 | pt3
   1  |  123 | 456 | 0001 
   2  |  123 | 456 | 0002
```

**Which is better? SUBSTRING or chunking the column?**

Answer (score 1):

If you want these conditions:

1. WHERE columnName start from 123456
2. WHERE columnName1 = 123 OR columnName2 = 456

Then use `LIKE` or `IN`.  The two conditions are:

```
WHERE columnName LIKE '123456%'
WHERE columnName1 = 123 OR columnName2 = 456
```

The first can be optimized using an index on `columnName`.  The second is not going to use an index in its current form (but you could force index usage using `UNION`/`UNION ALL` with simpler `WHERE` clauses.

Comment: Does LIKE is much preferred than SUBSTRING?

Comment: @JamVille . . . Much preferred.  When the pattern is a constant/parameter and does not begin with a wildcard, then it can make use of an index.